# Attemp to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.isCenceled()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, windows, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-storage

Upon running my React Native Android application, I encountered the following error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.isCanceled()' on a null object reference.

You can view the error displayed on the screen by referring to this image:
[This is the error that show on reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bREYI.png)

Upon dismissing the error, the application runs smoothly. However, upon reloading, the same error reappears.

Here is the content from the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "FirebaseProject1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

I attempted to search on Google and consult ChatGPT, but unfortunately, I was unable to successfully resolve the issue.